# how to detect twitter emoji that are typed continuly, in python

Tags: python, twitter, nltk

I am working with python 2.7 in windows and NLTK package.

I want to detect twitter emoji(emoticon) inside tweet. This code is able to detect specific emoji, in the condition that emoji is not continued with another emoji immediately.

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer,  word_tokenize
def negationDetection(tweet):
   words = word_tokenize(tweet)
   print words
   emoticonList = ['❤']
   i=0
   for word in words:
      if word in emoticonList:
          print "detected"
      i+=1
a = "Congratulations to my cousin James Daniel Brown for graduating from Texas Tech University ❤ go red raiders"
b = negationDetection(a)
```

The result is  >>> detected

but if the tweet is `a = "Congratulations to my cousin James Daniel Brown for graduating from Texas Tech University ❤❤❤ go red raiders"`

It is not detecting emoji inside tweet. How can I deal with this kind of situations? is there any paackage/tokenizer that can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should switch your `for` loops: `for word in emoticonList: if word in words`.

Comment: Tried but it is not working

Comment: Not familiar with NLTK but will `word_tokenize` parse `❤❤❤` as one token or as five? If parsed as one then `❤` will not be in `words`.

Comment: As one token. '\xe2\x9d\xa4\xf0\x9f\x8e\x89\xe2\x9d\xa4\xf0\x9f\x8e\x89\xe2\x9d\xa4'

Comment: Are you interested in an emoji anywhere in the line or only in words completely consisting of emojis?

Comment: Please post your solution as a answer instead.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I am interested anywhere in the line. I don't have enough reputations to make it as an answer.

Comment: Oh, you have. Anyone can post answers. As per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking, the only restriction is if you have <100 rep, you can answer your own question after 8 hours since you asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found

```
def negationDetection(tweet):
    emoticonList = ['❤']
    for i in emoticonList:
        if tweet.find(i) == -1:
            continue
        else:
            print "Found", i


a = "It's a good thing I didn't apply anywhere else.. American University 2020 ❤️❤️ URL"
b = negationDetection(a)
```

Now it works prefect.